# How do I correctly write a tuple list to a .txt file?

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

I am trying to maintain a list a names and times, sorted by increasing time.

```
def listfile (name, time):

    players = []
    strtime = str(time)
    players.append((name, strtime))
    with open("playersScores.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line != '\n':
                name, strtime = line.split(',')
                players.append((name, strtime))
    f.close()  

    players.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

    with open("playersScores.txt", "w") as f:
        for (name, strtime) in players:
            f.write("%s\n" % (name + "," + strtime))
    f.close()
```

This essentially works but it leaves a blank line below every line, except the newly added line.

I would like something like:

```
Bob,32.82
Bill,34.22
Joe,39.09
Bob,45.23
George,46.08
```

but I am getting:

```
Bob,32.82

Bill,34.22
Joe,39.09

Bob,45.23

George,46.08
```

`Bill,34.22` being the last entry.

Comment: take out the `\n` in your `f.write`\

Comment: Unless it's important that the file itself be readable in plain text, you could look into using the Pickle module instead

Comment: Does the file have to be human-readable? This seems like a job for [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)!

Comment: That would leave everything on a single line.

Comment: A .txt file was specifically requested.

Comment: look into using [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library. I swear it's magical and easy to use.

Comment: Did you try to strip the newlines that are in the file?

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski not sure how JSON would help here. If the file needs to be human-readable, then a csv is fine.

Comment: @AdamSmith Had an idea to insert his lists into a JSON and write it into the file. The newline worry vanishes. Anyway, has been answered already

Comment: @T.Lackey, try it and see if that is true. the only line that would probably be misformatted would be your newly added entry, which could be fixed by having `strtime +'\n'` for the first time you append to players (the one call that appends the new entry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when reading the file there is a `\n` at the end of each line that does not automatically get stripped off. In your code shown here the variable `strtime` still contains a `\n` character at the end.

```
name, strtime = line.split(',')
players.append((name, strtime))
```

The `\n` in the call to `f.write()` is fine. You just need to strip off the `\n` when you read. `rstrip()` will remove whitespace characters from the right side of the string.

Do this:

```
name, strtime = line.split(',')
players.append((name, strtime.rstrip()))
```

Comment: Exactly so. `line.strip().split(...)` is a common idiom for a reason! :)

Comment: Dang, beat my comment by a little bit. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're creating is technically a .csv file, you could also look into the `csv` module

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    new_lines = sorted(itertools.chain(reader, (name, strtime)),
                       key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
    f.seek(0)  # rewind to the beginning of the file
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
    # you must specify the lineterminator on Windows, or else open in binary mode
    # however csv.readers don't work in binary mode on Windows.
    writer.writerows(new_lines)
```

Note that this will give you some weird errors if you're deleting lines. This doesn't truncate the file before writing to it -- you're overwriting data, so replacing

```
1
3
5
7
```

with

```
2
4
8
```

Will give you

```
2
4
8
7  # oops!
```